# Eclipse is not functioning (f3, ctrl+space, Open Implementation via ctrl, Compile errors) correctly after i imported my Hybris project.

Tags: spring, eclipse, java-8, ide, sap-commerce-cloud

After i imported my Hybris 6.3 extension and custom extension to eclipse, it is not working properly in some extension(project) and working fine in other(project), even it is not showing compile error. I have re-installed other eclipse version like Neon and photon but it didn't worked out. 
I have tried deleting the .metadata folder from my workspace but the issue still persist.
 i tried opening eclipse.exe -clean from command prompt but it is not getting corrected. This is giving me a hard time. Please suggest me a fix.

If any other IDE could be used instead which is compatible for Hybris then i would try switching it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem you are facing is because of Hybris extension.

You can try

- Download/Install Eclipse
- Create new workspace
- Install the [Hybris Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sap-hybris-commerce-development-tools-eclipse) from the eclipse marketplace
- Import the platform (Click on `Import` > select `Import SAP Hybris platform` > select the platform path), the eclipse will import other dependent projects.

Comment: Well, I am using the same extension to import my project in eclipse. I have checked in hybris wiki. But the issue still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Eclipse related issue generally.

Try importing your extension projects alongwith the platform ext. project in an usual manner through "Import existing projects into workspace" followed by selecting all the projects and pressing F5 (Refresh).

If the issue persists select all the projects again and click on Projects -> Clean (Can be found on the tool bar along side File and Edit)